# How can I iterate over an array of collections containing arrays in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, eloquent, laravel-5.6, eager-loading, laravel-5.7

My collection is instantiated using the following query: `$ClassesCollection = Classes::with('Queue')->whereIn('user_course_id', UserCourse::select('id')->where('user_id', $user->id))->get();`

$ClassesCollection returns the desired result. However, I only want the `Queue` results.

So I split it this way

```php
$classes = [];

    foreach($ClassesCollection as $class){
        array_push($classes, $class->Queue);
    }
```

And now I have an array of collections, each holding arrays of `Queue`s.

How can I iterate over these collections to display the content of each array of `Queue`s separately in my view?

This is what `$classes` holds

```php
array:10 [▼
  0 => Collection {#968 ▼
    #items: array:12 [▼
      0 => Queue {#841 ▶}
      1 => Queue {#842 ▶}
      2 => Queue {#843 ▶}
      3 => Queue {#844 ▶}
      4 => Queue {#845 ▶}
      5 => Queue {#846 ▶}
      6 => Queue {#847 ▶}
      7 => Queue {#848 ▶}
      8 => Queue {#849 ▶}
      9 => Queue {#850 ▶}
      10 => Queue {#851 ▶}
      11 => Queue {#852 ▶}
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#969 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#970 ▶}
  3 => Collection {#971 ▶}
  4 => Collection {#972 ▶}
  5 => Collection {#973 ▶}
  6 => Collection {#974 ▶}
  7 => Collection {#975 ▶}
  8 => Collection {#976 ▶}
  9 => Collection {#977 ▶}
]
```

And each `Queue` holds several attributes such as `date` and `class_id`. So what can I do to display the content of each Queue?

EDIT: I thought there would be a cleaner way but this is how I solved my problem for anyone who comes across this.

```php
$count = 0;
foreach($classes as $collection => $queue){
       /*$count = count($queue) - 1;
       for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){
        echo $queue[$i]->date."\n";
       }*/
       foreach($queue as $Q){
        echo $Q->date."\n";
       }
}
```

The commented out code achieves the desired effect too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck):

```php
$queues = $ClassesCollection->pluck('Queue')->flatten();
```

Comment: That's very helpful, actually! Thank you.